# Loop exponential time in R with SQL queries

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I have a query that takes a lot of time to execute using RODBC(+3 hours):

```
    sqlQuery(dbhandle2,
             paste0("
                    USE RCC
                    SELECT
                      B.cCodCta,
                      A.dFecRep,
                      SUM(IIF(A.cCtaCnt LIKE '14_[1-6]%' OR A.cCtaCnt LIKE '81_302%', ISNULL(A.nSaldo, 0), 0)) AS 'nDeuDir' 
                    INTO ##tab_rcc_2
                    FROM DEUDSAL A
                    INNER JOIN ##tab_rcc_1 B
                      ON A.cCodSbs = B.cCodSbs
                    GROUP BY cCodCta,
                             dFecRep"))
```

But if use this query only for the first 4000 ID's (cCodCta):

```
    sqlQuery(dbhandle2,
             paste0("
                    USE RCC
                    SELECT
                      B.cCodCta,
                      A.dFecRep,
                      SUM(IIF(A.cCtaCnt LIKE '14_[1-6]%' OR A.cCtaCnt LIKE '81_302%', ISNULL(A.nSaldo, 0), 0)) AS 'nDeuDir' 
                    INTO ##tab_rcc_2
                    FROM DEUDSAL A
                    INNER JOIN ##tab_rcc_1 B
                      ON A.cCodSbs = B.cCodSbs
                    WHERE cCodCta IN ('ID1','ID2',...,'ID4000')
                    GROUP BY cCodCta,
                             dFecRep"))
```

It only takes 2 seconds. So I thought that creating a loop would solve the issue of time:

```
    tabMesesIncDeudaTot <- NULL
    for(i in 0:((length(cCodCta)%/%4000)-1)){
    temp <-         sqlQuery(dbhandle2,
             paste0("
                    USE RCC
                    SELECT
                      B.cCodCta,
                      A.dFecRep,
                      SUM(IIF(A.cCtaCnt LIKE '14_[1-6]%' OR A.cCtaCnt LIKE '81_302%', ISNULL(A.nSaldo, 0), 0)) AS 'nDeuDir' 
                    FROM DEUDSAL A
                    INNER JOIN ##tab_rcc_1 B
                      ON A.cCodSbs = B.cCodSbs
                    WHERE cCodCta IN ('",paste(cCodCta[(i*4000):(i*4000+4000-1),collapse = "','")],"')
                    GROUP BY cCodCta,
                             dFecRep"))
    tabMesesIncDeudaTot <- rbind(tabMesesIncDeudaTot,temp)
    }
```

My mistake, because the execution time grows exponentially when **i > 3**. I would appreciate any help in order to understand why it happens and how to optimize the execution time.

Comment: What is your data base?

Comment: ##tab_rcc_1 is a table with the detail of credit accounts that I'm interested in obtaining information and DEUDSAL is a very heavy table containing the history of debts for each credit granted in the last 10 years in a country.

Comment: In general, I suggest against using `rbind` iteratively like this. It is usually faster to do `ret <- lapply(0:length(...), function(i) { sqlQuery(...);})` and then `out <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, ret)` (perhaps with `stringsAsFactors=F`).

Comment: We know nothing about your table structure to optimise your query. Please provide full table DDL statements, index definitions, record counts, hardware spec, descriptions of key columns